# Why can't I set Egg's instance variable i by calling Yolk's setter method?

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to Java about 1 week into it and I've run into a slight problem.
I have the inner class Yolk and I'm trying to set the instance variable i by calling Yolk's setI method.

```
public class Egg {
    private int i;
    Yolk y;

    class Yolk {
        public  void setI(int value){
        i = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Egg e = new Egg();
        e.y.setI(5);
        System.out.println("i= "+ e.i);
}
```

When I run my program I get the NullPointerException and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: Your egg does not have a yolk yet, just the space where it should be.

Comment: Ah! was overlooking things! Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yolk y hasn't been instantiated yet.

```
Yolk y = new Yolk();
```

Comment: Thank you! was so simple, just flew over my head.